# Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") ERROR when run : python configure.py

Tags: software-installation, qt

I followed this [link](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/wiki/Compiling-PyQt5-on-Ubuntu-12.04) to install `PyQt5` on Raspbian.
First I cross compiled Qt5 ([this link](http://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi_Beginners_Guide)) for Raspberry and executed an example.  It worked fine.

When executing this command:

```
python configure.py --qmake ~/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake --sip-incdir ../sip-4.16.5/siplib
```

I received the following error:

```
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
/usr/local/qt5pi/bin/qmake: 1: /usr/local/qt5pi/bin/qmake: ELF: not found
/usr/local/qt5pi/bin/qmake: 2: /usr/local/qt5pi/bin/qmake: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v3. Use the
--qmake flag to specify the correct version of qmake.
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Are you running the `python configure.py` command on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: yes,I run: `python configure.py --qmake ~/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake --sip-incdir ../sip-4.16.5/siplib`. and if I run `python configure.py` without any arguman it say: `Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake`